# Meteor Collection Find and Return Two Queries

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my helper, I currently can return

```
 myStuff.find({from: name1, to: name2});
```

or

```
 myStuff.find({from: name2, to: name1});
```

**How can I return the results from both?** *

I've tried various combinations using $and but I'm getting my syntax confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
 myStuff.find({$or: [{from: name1, to: name2}, {from: name2, to: name1}]});
```